# Get UserId of account executing MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I have a requirement to log the domain userid that the build is executing under.  I tried tapping into WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name like the following:

```
  <Target Name="Test123" BeforeTargets="BackupWebApp">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <UserId>$([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name)</UserId>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="UserId : $(UserId)" Importance="high"/>
  </Target>
```

But I this error:

The function "GetCurrent" on type "System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity" is not available for execution as an MSBuild property function.

Is there some other way I can get the userid of the person or service account performing the build?

I know about $(USERNAME) - but I'm using NTLM and not specifying a userid or password, so it always seems to be blank.

Thanks-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you want to run some code within MsBuild, and it's not available as a property function or similar, use CodeTaskFactory. More boilerplate, but of course also more powerful:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="GetUserName" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
           AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll" >
  <ParameterGroup>
    <UserName ParameterType="System.String" Output="True"/>
  </ParameterGroup>
  <Task>
    <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
      UserName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
    </Code>
  </Task>
</UsingTask>

<Target Name="ShowUserName">
  <GetUserName>
    <Output PropertyName="UserName" TaskParameter="UserName" />
  </GetUserName>
  <Message Text="UserName = $(UserName)" />
</Target>
```